# CVLC fails to connect to D-Bus session

Tags: python, ubuntu, vlc, dbus

I'm having an issue using cvlc to stream. I'm currently using Ubuntu 17.10 and VLC 2.2.6 as seen below. I start the stream through a python sub-process command. Afterwards, the following is printed to the terminal. Any help is appreciated.

```
VLC media player 2.2.6 Umbrella (revision 2.2.6-0-g1aae78981c)
[000055e7514d3d28] dbus interface error: Failed to connect to the D-Bus session daemon: Failed to connect to socket /tmp/dbus-1msq9as6ke: Connection refused
[000055e7514d3d28] core interface error: no suitable interface module
[000055e7513c5a88] core libvlc error: interface "dbus,none" initialization failed
[000055e7514d3d28] dummy interface: using the dummy interface module...
[00007fc8c0006c18] x264 encoder: using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast LZCNT

[00007fc8c0006c18] x264 encoder: profile High, level 3.0

[00007fc8c0006c18] x264 encoder: final ratefactor: 38.84

[00007fc8cc4ffbd8] stream_out_transcode stream out: input interval 33333 (base 1)
[00007fc8cc4ffbd8] stream_out_transcode stream out: output interval 66666 (base 1)
[00007fc8c0006c18] x264 encoder: using SAR=715/714

[00007fc8c0006c18] x264 encoder: using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast LZCNT

[00007fc8c0006c18] x264 encoder: profile High, level 3.0

[00007fc8c8000e08] core input error: ES_OUT_SET_(GROUP_)PCR  is called too late (pts_delay increased to 312 ms)
[00007fc8c8000e08] core input error: ES_OUT_RESET_PCR called
[00007fc8c8000e08] core input error: ES_OUT_SET_(GROUP_)PCR  is called too late (pts_delay increased to 323 ms)
[00007fc8c8000e08] core input error: ES_OUT_RESET_PCR called
...
```

This is the code i use to start the sub-process. Opencv is piped into the sub-process's stdin.

```
pipe_out = subprocess.Popen([ 'cvlc', "--demux=rawvideo", "--rawvid-fps=30",
                "--rawvid-width=715",
                "--rawvid-height=576",
                "--rawvid-chroma=RV24",
                "-",
                "--sout",
                "#transcode{vcodec=h264,vb=200,fps=15,width=715,height=576}:std{access=http{mime=video/x-flv},mux=ffmpeg{mux=flv},dst=:5052/stream.flv}"],
                stdin = subprocess.PIPE, stdout = subprocess.PIPE)
```

Answer (score 1):

Fixed it by adding permissions via `sudo chown username.username -R .dbus`.
Credit goes to [Harris](https://askubuntu.com/questions/905466/dropbox-icon-not-working-unable-to-create-dbus-session-bus#comment1421693_905466).